# How to add multiple search fields in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I want to add a functionality where multiple search is possible. I'll be providing an input field for that, just like SO does for adding `Tags` . I want to replicate the same.

How would I do that?

Comment: look at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) tagging

Comment: Is there a CDN version of select2?

Comment: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/select2/

Comment: Last question. Do I need to include all the cdn files under version 3.4.4?

Comment: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.4/select2.css

Comment: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.4/select2.js

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bA3L4/1/

Comment: I tried this. It's not working. Please have a look. http://jsfiddle.net/u369U/

Comment: you didn't include jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZw7x/1/ see the first dropdown in the left panel

Comment: see or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZw7x/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42726/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user1162512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select2 plugin to do this

```
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.4/select2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.4/select2.js"></script>
    <input type="text" id='selec2'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#1").select2({
            tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
            maximumInputLength: 10,
            tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
        });
    })
    </script>  
</body>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZw7x/)